# can I configure Nginx to enable HTTP in a documentRoot and HTTPS in another documentRoot?

Tags: nginx, https, http, documentroot

I have SSL enabled via certBot and reversing proxy for my Node-js and everything works fine if my clients request to **`https://`**`example.com/` they will see my web site under `/var/www/`**`html/`** Document Root Folder.
besides, I want to config Nginx so that if clients request to **`http://`**`example.com` see another web site under`var/www/`**`noSsl/`** Document Root Folder.
I actually confuse how to config these two requests in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure this.

You need to have two separate `server` blocks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/noSsl;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/html;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I try that one before but it actually redirects me on HTTPS everytime and I can not see noSsl contents. There is no config for redirecting though:(

Comment: Then your domain might have some HSTS headers set that force browsers to go to the https version of the site.